# How can i redirect pull request from main branch to another branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, open-source, pull

I had to create a PR to a development branch from my own branch in a team project but i mistakenly created a PR to the main branch. what can i do now? can i redirect this PR to dev branch somehow?(Github)